# vim: Use ctrl-Q for visual block mode in vim-gnome

Tags: vim

I use vim on windows and linux. On linux I would like to set ctrl-Q to visual block selection, but still maintain behave mswin which sets ctrl-v to paste.

How can I keep behave mswin and use ctrl-Q for visual block mode?

edit: I though mswin would also map ctrl-Q to visual block mode, but in vim-gnome ctrl-Q does nothing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

first of all, I highly recommend you to **forget the windows vim shortcuts if you work on a linux box**. such as: ctrl-v, ctrl-q, ctrl-c ...

well you must think this isn't the answer to your question. now I post the "answer".

to make `ctrl-q` work as `ctrl-v (block selection)` on a linux box, you have to tell, you work with  **gvim** or **vim in terminal**.

#### Gvim

If it was **gvim**, it is easier, just create a mapping, like:

```
nnoremap <c-q> <c-v>
```

#### Terminal Vim

If you want to make `<c-q>` work in your terminal vim, you need to understand the default `<C-q>` has special meaning in your terminal settings.

In your terminal, pressing `<c-q>` will sent `stty start` signal. This is important when you first `stop` your terminal output scrolling(by `ctrl-s`), and then you want to resume.  That is, in terminal vim, if you pressed `C-q`, it will be captured first by terminal. You can of course change that rule, by disable the `stty start` definition. like:

```
stty start undef
```

you could add this to your `.bashrc` file (I assume you were using bash) if you want to make it as default.

with this line executed, you can create the same mapping `nnoremap <c-q> <c-v>` in your vim, and pressing `<c-q>` in normal mode, vim is gonna enter block-wise selection mode.

After all, again, I suggest you forget the windows mapping if you work on linux box.

Comment: But wait, what I don't understand is that thats is just remapping ctrl+v to ctrl+q. With behave mswin ctrl+v is paste so that will just make ctrl+q to a paste from the * register won't it? I want ctrl+v to paste and ctrl+q to enter visual select. Working on win and linux I can't have different mappings for each that would drive me crazy and being a windows admin for many years behave mswin just feels more natural.

Comment: Also I use gvim (vim-gnome in this case) exclusively if that simplifies things.

Comment: @user1028270 if you want `c-v` to do `p` (paste), you can create mapping:`nnoremap <c-v> p`  with the mapping in my answer (`<c-q> -> <c-v>`) it does what you want. If you have good reason to use win-keymap on linux box, it is fine. anyway for me, it is good to hear that a windows admin use vim as main editor.. I ever wrote a relative long win-batch file (400lines), I did it in my linux vim. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your terminal settings (`stty start undef` to allow using `ctrl q` as mentioned in Kent's answer) to be able to use `ctrl v` for paste, you can make `ctrl v` paste only in visual and insert modes, and make it block select in normal mode:

```
" Paste from clipboard when in insert mode.
imap <C-V> <ESC>"+gpa
" Paste from clipboard when in visual mode. (Replace whatever is selected in visual mode.)
vmap <C-V> "+gp
```

You can also copy to the clipboard from visual mode:

```
" Copy selection to clipboard when in visual mode.
vmap <C-C> "+y
```