# vim keyboard mapping problems on mac OSX

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2

## 1.Env

vim7.3+zsh+iTerm2 on mavericks

## 2. Mapping Problem

Here are my problem list:

1. My vim could not get some shortcuts: `<C-q>`,`<C-s>`,`<A-Left|Right|..>`,`<D-char>`.
2. I could not map some special keys such as   `<A-char>` , `<A-S-char>` , `<C-A-char>`in mac.

### `<C-q>` and `<C-s>`

In iTerm2, `<C-q>` will delete whole line, (and `<C-s>` will launch `Fwd-i-search`).
It doesn't behave like start/stop character , so that I thought this problem is nothing to do with `stty start` and `stty stop`.
**But after I add this into `~/.zshrc`, I surprised to see that the map for `<C-q>` and `<C-s>` works well in Vim.** At the same time it doesn't change the behavior of `<C-q>` and `<C-s>` in iTerm2(I don't know why).

```
stty start undef
stty stop undef
```

### `<A-char>` problem in mac

In mac, mappings for `<A-char>` won't directly work in mac.

```
:inoremap <A-u> type some string A-u
:inoremap <A-p> type some string A-p
:inoremap
i  õ           * type some string A-u
i  ð           * type some string A-p
```

As far as I know about `<A-char>` in mac, hit `<A-u>` will print nothing but with a sound alert. hit `<A-p>` will print `π`. I found that map for `π` works well.

```
:inoremap π type some string A-p
```

Is it possible to map `<A-u>` in vim?

Another complex question, is it possible for `<A-S-char>`, `<C-A-char>`

```
:map <A-S-p> not work
:map ∏ works well(A-S-p will print `∏`)

:map <C-A-p> not work
:map <C-π> still not work

:map <C-S-p> do work
```

Another complex question related above, is it possible mapping `<C-A-char>`?

### `<A-Left|Right|UP|Down`

In iTerm2 , hitting `<A-Left|...` will result in(iTerm2 doesn't bind any shortcut for them.):

```
<A-Up> print 'A' with a sound alert.
<A-Down> print 'B' with a sound alert.
<A-Left> print 'D' with a sound alert.
<A-Down> print 'C' with a sound alert.
```

In vim, `<A-Left|...` is same as `<Left><Right><Up><Down>` in insert mode , normal mode, visual mdoe  and Ex Mode, etc.

### `<D-char>`

Some keys about `<D-char>` are iTerms's own hotkeys, such as :
1. `<D-q>` will quit iTerm2
1. `<D-w>` will close current tab in iTerm2

On the other hand, the other keys such as `<D-s>` are not hotkey, and do not print any char in vim and terminal. Is it possible to map them in vim?

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim: Use ctrl-Q for visual block mode in vim-gnome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806168/vim-use-ctrl-q-for-visual-block-mode-in-vim-gnome)

Answer (score 1):

## Map `<C-1>`

Vim doesn't provide keycode `<C-1>`, but you can use other unused vim keycodes instead

Potentially unused Vim keycodes that can be used include:

```
<F13> to <F37>
<S-F13> to <S-F37>
<xF1> to <xF4>
<S-xF1> to <S-xF4>
```

Type `:set termcap` to see which vim keycodes are unused.

If you want to use hotkey `Ctrl+1`, map it to Esc Sequence (such as `^[C-1`) in terminal preference first, then bind this terminal keycode with an unused vim keycode such as `<F13>`, `<xF1>`, `<t_bc>`, etc.

```
"bind vim keycode `<F13>` to terminal keycode `^[C-1`
:set <F13>=^[C-1
:imap <F13> Input some characters
```

> For more details, refer to [fastcodes in vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim)

---

## Map `<A-char>`

By default,  `<A-char>` will print special character in mac. In generally, you can map this special character. Or **you can remap `<Alt>` as `Meta` in your terminal**.

## Map `<C-A-char>` and `<D-char>`

Same with `<C-1>`, if you use termainal vim you could use  fastcodes instead of.

1. Bind `<C-A-char>` with terminal any keycodes, for example :  `^[C-A-a`
2. Set vim fastkeycodes and do mapping:

Mapping:

```
:set <C-A-a>=^[C-A-a
:map <C-A-a> Input some characters
```

Comment: Sorry that my hunch wasn't right then. You should better edit this into your question, it's not an answer. And you might get better answers on e Mac-specific forum, not here on SO, because this isn't programming-related and so strictly speaking off-topc.